# Is it possible to have more than one key/lambda for python's max/min functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, max

The following code is broken:

```py
>>> import operator
>>> max(enumerate([[7, {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 1}], [0, {'profit': 0, 'buy_idx': None, 'sell_idx': None}], [7, {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 2}]]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    max(enumerate([[7, {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 1}], [0, {'profit': 0, 'buy_idx': None, 'sell_idx': None}], [7, {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 2}]]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but I am fairly certain it's because `max` is evaluating the dictionaries and trying to compare them, even though they're not the first elements of the list.

I know if I could use `key=lambda x: x[0]` then only the first element of each list (integers) would be compared, which would fix my problem.

```py
>>> max([[7, {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 1}], [0, {'profit': 0, 'buy_idx': None, 'sell_idx': None}], [7, {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 2}]], key=lambda x: x[0])
[7, {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 1}]
```

However, I'm already using the key via `operator.itemgetter` which is not really negotiable because I need to fetch the maximum element index concurrently.

So I'm in the predicament where I have two lambdas I need to pass into python's key argument.

Is that even possible? If not, what's my best solution?

Comment: To fix the error `key=lambda x: x[1][0]`, IIUC

Comment: `itemgetter(1)` is returning the list that contains the number and dictionary, so you're trying to compare those lists. And that will try to compare the dictionaries.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny that will fix the error but does it also enable me to get the maximum element index?

Comment: Of course, why wouldn't it? You're still using `enumerate()` to get the indexes.

Comment: @notacorn yes, of course. Why do you think `itemgetter(1)` would *prevent that*? No key would, since `max` doesn't return the maximum *key value*, it returns the values *corresponding to the maximum key value*

Comment: @notacorn - you get a tuple of `index, max(element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the dictionary with max *profit* and the index works without copying the *profit* value as first element in a `list`. I slightly modified the dictionaries.

```
d = [{'profit': 3, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 1},
     {'profit': 0, 'buy_idx': None, 'sell_idx': None},
     {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 2}]

index, maxdict = max(enumerate(d), key=lambda x: x[1]['profit'])
print(f'max profit in {maxdict} at index {index}')
```

Output

```
max profit in {'profit': 7, 'buy_idx': 0, 'sell_idx': 2} at index 2
```